# How to create a venn diagram from a grouped data frame based on a single column?

Tags: r, venn-diagram, grouped-table

Interestingly, all the libraries and resources I have found either use lists or multiple columns.
I would like to create a Venn diagram based on a grouped data frame (one column group and another column with items to be compared). What would be the easiest approach?

```
data.frame(groups = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 8)), items = c(LETTERS[1:10], LETTERS[7:14]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just transform the data into what the packages are expecting. From my own experience when creating `nVennR`, you cannot anticipate every entry format. That is why developers tend to rely on users to convert data:

```
t <- data.frame(groups = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 8)), items = c(LETTERS[1:10], LETTERS[7:14]))

cnames <- levels(as.factor(t$groups))
r <- list()
for (c in cnames){
  r[[c]] <- as.vector(t[t[,1]==c,2])
}
```

Now, `r` has a list of vectors, which is what some packages (including `nVennR`) expect:

```
library(nVennR)

myV <- plotVenn(r)

listVennRegions(myV)

$`0, 1 (2)`
[1] "K" "L" "M" "N"

$`1, 0 (1)`
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"

$`1, 1 (1, 2)`
[1] "G" "H" "I" "J"
```